# Where to put .sty file

Tags: packages, installing, texmf

I have made a long list of macros that I have put in a style file. I have been working with this same style file for many years now. I would like to put it somewhere in my TeX tree, so that I don't have to copy it each time to a new location. Furthermore, each time I add a new macro I have to add it in all the copies...

Is there some folder in `/var/bin/share/local/texmf/etc/opt` or whatever where I can just put the file and then forget about everything? I don't like to have the style file in my home directory (I don't want to see it).

I don't know anything about the TeXMF tree, and I would like to keep it that way.

I use Linux Mint (very similar to Ubuntu), and I installed LaTeX via `apt-get install texlive`. I have Google'd for the question, but I always get very complicated and unsatisfactory responses.

Comment: I think the following link to the tex subforum on here should be able to answer all of your questions, its rather comprehensive. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). See in this reply in [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/15717). Very detailed 2010 TUGboat article [Appendix A: Installing personal packages](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf) is written by [Prof.Enrico Gregorio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)